# Using AWS CDK, How to connect an AWS Load balancer and an AWS Interface VPC Endpoint together

Tags: amazon-web-services, network-programming, amazon-vpc, aws-cdk, vpc-endpoint

**Background:**
We're using AWS Cloud Development Kit (CDK) 2.5.0.

Manually using the AWS Console and hard-coded IP addresses, Route 53 to an ALB (Application Load Balancer) to a private Interface VPC Endpoint to a private REST API-Gateway (and so on..) works. See image below.

**Code:**
We're trying to code this manual solution via CDK, but are stuck on how to get and use the IP addresses or in some way hook up the load balancer to the Interface VPC Endpoint. (Endpoint has 3 IP addresses, one per availability zone in the region.)

The ALB needs a Target Group which targets the IP addresses of the Interface VPC Endpoint. (Using an "instance" approach instead of IP addresses, we tried using `InstanceIdTarget` with the endpoint's `vpcEndpointId`, but that failed. We got the error `Instance ID 'vpce-WITHWHATEVERWASHERE' is not valid` )

Using CDK, we created the following (among other things) using the `aws_elasticloadbalancingv2` module:

- `ApplicationLoadBalancer` (ALB)
- `ApplicationTargetGroup` (ATG) aka Target Group

We were hopeful about `aws_elasticloadbalancingv2_targets` similar to `aws_route53_targets`, but no luck. We know the `targets` property of the `ApplicationTargetGroup` takes an array of `IApplicationLoadBalancerTarget` objects, but that's it.

```
  :
import { aws_ec2 as ec2 } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
  :
import { aws_elasticloadbalancingv2 as loadbalancing } from 'aws-cdk-lib';

// endpointSG, loadBalancerSG, vpc, ... are defined up higher
        const endpoint = new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint(this, `ABCEndpoint`, {
            service: {
                name: `com.amazonaws.us-east-1.execute-api`,
                port: 443
            },
            vpc,
            securityGroups: [endpointSG],
            privateDnsEnabled: false,
            subnets: { subnetGroupName: "Private" }
        });


        const loadBalancer = new loadbalancing.ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, 'abc-${config.LEVEL}-load-balancer', {
            vpc: vpc,
            vpcSubnets: { subnetGroupName: "Private" },
            internetFacing: false,
            securityGroup: loadBalancerSG
        });

        const listenerCertificate = loadbalancing.ListenerCertificate.fromArn(config.ARNS.CERTIFICATE)
        const listener = loadBalancer.addListener('listener', {
            port: 443,
            certificates: [ listenerCertificate ]
        });

        let applicationTargetGroup = new loadbalancing.ApplicationTargetGroup(this, 'abc-${config.LEVEL}-target-group', {
            port: 443,
            vpc: vpc,
            // targets: [ HELP ], - how to get the IApplicationLoadBalancerTarget objects?  
        })
        listener.addTargetGroups( 'abc-listener-forward-to-target-groups', { 
            targetGroups: [applicationTargetGroup]
        } );
```

As you can see above, we added a listener to the ALB. We added the Target Group to the listener.

Some of the resources we used:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationTargetGroup.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2//docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2_targets.InstanceIdTarget.html and related.
- [How to get PrivateIPAddress of VPC Endpoint in CDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57267594/how-to-get-privateipaddress-of-vpc-endpoint-in-cdk) but this did not help.

In case visualizing the set up via an image helps, here's a close approximation of what we're going for.
[image]

Any help populating that `targets` property of the `ApplicationTargetGroup` with `IApplicationLoadBalancerTarget` objects is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Although it doesn't have a diagram, the question on AWS https://repost.aws of "How to connect a Load balancer and an Interface VPC Endpoint together using CDK?" also exists. An AWS expert has responded to that over there.

Comment: If a person decides to go a whole other simpler route but also ensures security is in place as needed, AWS CDK: Use Lambda with Application Load Balancer - https://sbstjn.com/blog/aws-cdk-lambda-loadbalancer-vpc-certificate/ exists. It has its cons though such as public internet traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/accessing-an-aws-api-gateway-via-static-ip-addresses-provided-by-aws-global-accelerator/

This blog shows how to configure the architecture given in the question using AWS console (just disable the global accelerator option). The key takeaway is that the application load balancer uses target type IP and resolves the VPC endpoint domain name manually in step 2. The other two options, instance (target is an EC2 instances) and lambda (target is an AWS Lambda function) cannot be used.

The `ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint` construct has no output which directly gives an IP address. The underlying CloudFormation resource also does not support it. Instead, you will have to use the `vpcEndpointDnsEntries` property of `ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint` and resolve the domain names to IP addresses in your code (the console configuration also required the same domain name resolution). You can use an [IpTarget](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2_targets.IpTarget.html) object in your [ApplicationTargetGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2//docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationTargetGroup.html).

At this point, you will run into one final roadblock due to how CDK works under the hood.
[image: cdk structure from documentation]
If you have all your resources defined in one CDK application, the value for each parameter (or a reference to the value using an underlying CloudFormation functions like Ref, GetAtt, etc.) needs to be available before the synthesize step, since that's when all templates are generated. AWS CDK uses [tokens](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/tokens.html) for this purpose, which during synthesis resolve to values such as `{'Fn::GetAtt': ['EndpointResourceLogicalName', 'DnsEntries']`. However since we need the actual value of the DNS entry to be able to resolve it, the token value won't be useful.

One way to fix this issue is to have two completely independent CDK applications structured this way:

- Application A with VPC and interface endpoint. Define the `vpcEndpointDnsEntries` and VPC-ID as outputs using [CfnOutput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2//docs/aws-cdk-lib.CfnOutput.html).
- Application B with the rest of the resources. You will have to write code to read outputs of the CloudFormation stack created by Application A. You can use [Fn.importValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2//docs/aws-cdk-lib.Fn.html#static-importwbrvaluesharedvaluetoimport) for VPC ID, but you cannot use it for the DnsEntries output since it would again just resolve to a Fn::ImportValue based token. You need to read the actual value of the stack output, using the AWS SDK or some other option. Once you have the domain name, you can resolve it in your typescript code (I am not very familiar with typescript, this might require a third party library).

Image credits:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/apps.html

Answer (score 1):

try this using a custome ressource to get eni ip addresses :
https://repost.aws/questions/QUjISNyk6aTA6jZgZQwKWf4Q/how-to-connect-a-load-balancer-and-an-interface-vpc-endpoint-together-using-cdk

Comment: Thank you for the link to the "How to connect a Load balancer and an Interface VPC Endpoint together using CDK?" AWS re:Post post. Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem glad that helps you ^^

Comment: This solution worked with CDK 2.9, to get the VPCEndpoint IP